# Horizontal ScrollView with absolute position React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to put a horizontal scrollview on top of this map but it doesn't scroll. What am I doing wrong? 
[image]

```
  <ScrollView
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 50,
        }}
        horizontal
        contentContainerStyle={{
          width: screen.width,
          height: 120,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
```

Answer (score 2):

okay i solved this by not specifying the width in contentContainerStyle